# Codeigniter Form validation problem

Tags: codeigniter

Please please please can someone help me

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->helper('cookie');

  $data = array();


  if($_POST) { 
   // Set validation rules including additional validation for uniqueness
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('yourname', 'Your Name', 'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('youremail', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('friendname', 'Friends Name', 'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('friendemail', 'Friends Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');

   // Run the validation and take action
   if($this->form_validation->run()) { 
    echo 'valid;
   }
  }
  else{
   echo 'problem';
  }
```

Form validation is coming back with no errors can cany one see why?

Answer (score 1):

Is it actually echoing 'valid'?  (you're missing an apostrophe there, btw)

The code you show will only echo 'problem' when $_POST is false, not when validation fails.
Without knowing more, it may be as simple as:

```
// Run the validation and take action
if($this->form_validation->run()) { 
 echo('valid');
} else {
 echo('invalid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this **without** checking if $_POST is set - not really needed:

```
//validation rules here
//
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
     //do whatever that shall be run on succeed
} else {
     $this->load->view('form'); //load the form
}
```

Read more about the controller part [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller)